capturing request and response data with OKHttp with bytebuddy android showing error :
trying to capture the OKHttp data request and response with byteBuddy Android, got this error.
what approach should I follow? how can I intercept OKHttp data Automatically with byteBudyy android?
here is the error
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal method name interface okhttp3.Authenticator for public final okhttp3.Authenticator okhttp3.OkHttpClient.-deprecated_authenticator()
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.InstrumentedType$Default.validated(InstrumentedType.java:1746)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.MethodRegistry$Default.prepare(MethodRegistry.java:519)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.inline.RedefinitionDynamicTypeBuilder.toTypeWriter(RedefinitionDynamicTypeBuilder.java:213)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.inline.AbstractInliningDynamicTypeBuilder.toTypeWriter(AbstractInliningDynamicTypeBuilder.java:127)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase$UsingTypeWriter.make(DynamicType.java:4057)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase.make(DynamicType.java:3741)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase$Delegator.make(DynamicType.java:3993)
at com.rnadigital.monita_android.MyApplicationKt.setupOkHttpBuilderByteBuddy(MyApplication.kt:84)
at com.rnadigital.monita_android.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.kt:42)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1316)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6998)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2236)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)

here is my code
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Byte Buddy setup to intercept methods in OkHttpClient
        ByteBuddy()
            .redefine(OkHttpClient::class.java)
          .method(named<MethodDescription?>("newCall")
            .and(not(named("-deprecated_authenticator")))
            .and(not(isDeclaredBy(Authenticator::class.java))))
            .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(OkHttpInterceptor::class.java))
            .make()
            .load(
                this.javaClass.classLoader,
                AndroidClassLoadingStrategy.Wrapping(this.filesDir)
            )

        // Now create the OkHttpClient instance, which will be affected by the instrumentation
        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()

        // Example of making a request to test the interceptor
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url("https://example.com")
            .build()

        val call = okHttpClient.newCall(request)
        val response = call.execute()
        println("Response: ${response.body?.string()}")
    }
}

class OkHttpInterceptor {
    @RuntimeType
    fun intercept(
        @This proxy: Any,
        @Origin method: Method,
        @AllArguments args: Array<Any>
    ): Any {
        // Log the request details
        if (args.isNotEmpty() && args[0] is Request) {
            val request = args[0] as Request
            println("Request URL: ${request.url}")
            println("Request Headers: ${request.headers}")
            println("Request Body: ${request.body}")
        }

        // Call the original method
        val result = method.invoke(proxy, *args)

        // Log the response details if applicable
        if (result is Response) {
            println("Response Code: ${result.code}")
            println("Response Body: ${result.body?.string()}")
        }

        return result
    }
}

please suggest some reference code for this if available for android.
can I use custom OKHttp  client
val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
.addInterceptor(LoggingInterceptor())
.build()

or is there any other approach ?

update my question , please have a look @Robert

Define with(TypeValidation.DISABLED). The minus symbol is not normally allowed within a Java identifier, this is what this warning is about.

thanks for this, added the changes but got stuck with a new error, please help me sir link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/79108108/7605556
